# NSTextView not working

Tags: objective-c, nstextview

Hi Community,

I'm working with a NSTextView, and I can't tell you how frustrating it is. I'm using NSAttributedStrings, so I've set the textStorage to a variable, told it to begin editing, and then I've been using appendAttributedString on the textStroage. The first time I click the button to update the NSTextView, I get this error message:

-[NSNull _isDefaultFace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff70bdefa0

the second time I click the button, the NSTextView goes completely blank, and when I click it (as if trying to select it's text), I get this message:

_NSLayoutTreeLineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex invalid glyph index 0

What could be causing this?? I've been trying to get this work for a few hours now, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

~Josh

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have been trying to use two different font sizes and the NSTextView wasn't liking it